# loop For, R - Incluir função no For e salvar o resultado em um objeto

Tags: r, lógica

```
install.packages("xlsx")
install.packages("stringr")
library(xlsx)   #pacote para ler os arquivos do excel
library(stringr)
library(e1071)  #pacote para calcular a curotse e o skewness


#Função que realiza calculos que preciso
calculos <- function(empresa){

  # calculando o retorno
  retorno <- diff(log(empresa[,5])) 
  #calculando media do retorno
  media_retorno <- mean(retorno)
  #calculando o risco
  desvio_retorno <- sd(retorno)

  #os 10 menores valores
  minimo <- sort(retorno, decreasing = FALSE)
  #os 10 maiores valores
  maximo <- sort(retorno, decreasing = TRUE)

  #somando os 10 maiores valores
  soma_10_max <- sum(maximo[1:10])
  #somando os 10 menores valores
  soma_10_min <- sum(minimo[1:10])

  #somando os 20 maiores valores
  soma_20_max <- sum(maximo[1:20])
  #somando os 20 menores valores
  soma_20_min <- sum(minimo[1:20])

  #somando os 50 maiores valores
  soma_50_max <- sum(maximo[1:50])
  #somando os 50 menores valores
  soma_50_min <- sum(minimo[1:50])

  #Calculando a curtorse com o pacote e1071
  curtose <- kurtosis(retorno, type = 1)
  #Calculando o Skewness com o pacote e1071
  skewness <- skewness(retorno, type=1)
  #Calculando o shapiro
  shapiro <- shapiro.test(retorno)


  distancia_10_max <- (mean(maximo[1:10]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)
  distancia_10_min <- (mean(minimo[1:10]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)

  distancia_20_max <- (mean(maximo[1:20]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)
  distancia_20_min <- (mean(minimo[1:20]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)

  distancia_50_max <- (mean(maximo[1:50]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)
  distancia_50_min <- (mean(minimo[1:50]) - mean(retorno))/sd(retorno)


  #Cria um vetor com todos os resultados dos calculos que realizamos.
  result_calculos <- c(media_retorno, desvio_retorno, soma_10_max,
                       soma_20_max, soma_50_max, soma_10_min, soma_20_min, 
                       soma_50_min, curtose, skewness, shapiro, 
                       distancia_10_max,
                       distancia_20_max, distancia_50_max, distancia_10_min, 
                       distancia_20_min, distancia_50_min)
  print(result_calculos)  #exibe os resultados. 
}



#Lista todos os arquivos de uma pasta
nome_arquivo <- list.files() 

# lendo os arquivos que estão na pasta, i é a posição do nome do arquivo
for(i in 1:length(nome_arquivo)){
  tmp <- read.xlsx(nome_arquivo[i], sheetIndex =1,startRow=4)
  nome <- substr(nome_arquivo[i],1,nchar(nome_arquivo[i])-5)
  assign(nome, tmp)
  rm(nome)
  rm(tmp)
}
```

Como utilizar uma função dentro do for e cada resultado salvar como uma linha de um data-frame?

Como posso incluir no for que lê os arquivos da pasta a função que criei que realiza os cálculos que preciso? Os resultados desses cálculos devem ser salvos em um data-frame onde cada linha é o vetor de resultados da função que criei.

Comment: Porquê o tag `rstudio`? Esse tag só deve ser usado se a pergunta for sobre algo que só acontece em RStudio.

Comment: Tem duas vezes `soma_20_max`, talvez a segunda vez seja `soma_50_max`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer o que quer com duas aplicações de `lapply`, a melhor maneira de o fazer.
Com o ciclo `for` e `assign`, fica com vários dataframes no `.GlobalEnv`, com `lapply` fica com uma lista que os mantém todos no mesmo sítio. É melhor prática deixar o `.GlobalEnv` bem arrumado e além disso é muito mais fácil processá-los depois.

```
nome_arquivo <- list.files() 

ler <- lapply(nome_arquivo, function(arq){
  tmp <- tryCatch(read.xlsx(arq, sheetIndex = 1, startRow = 4),
                  error = function(e) e)
  nome <- substr(arq, 1, nchar(arq) - 5)
  list(nome = nome, dados = tmp)
})

ok <- sapply(ler, function(L) !inherits(L[["dados"]], "error"))
lista_erros <- lapply(ler[!ok], `[[`, "nome")
lista_dados <- lapply(ler[ok], `[[`, "dados")
names(lista_dados) <- sapply(ler[ok], `[[`, "nome")

lista_result <- lapply(lista_dados, calculos)
```